# Built-in function to capitalise the first letter of each word

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pascalcasing

I don't want to create a custom function for that if such function already exists in SQL Server.

Input string: `This is my string to convert`
Expected output: `This Is My String To Convert`

Comment: Technically, that would be PascalCase.

Comment: @thomas, technically it is neither, its just a string of capitalized words

Comment: @nathan gonzalez - I stand corrected.

Answer (score 27):

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[InitCap] ( @InputString varchar(4000) ) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(4000)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @Index          INT
DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1)
DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1)
DECLARE @OutputString   VARCHAR(4000)

SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString)
SET @Index = 1

WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1)
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END

    IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
        SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char))

    SET @Index = @Index + 1
END

RETURN @OutputString

END



Declare @str nvarchar(100)
SET @str = 'my string to convert'
SELECT @str = [dbo].[InitCap](@str)
SELECT @str
```

Answer (score 16):

AFAIK, SQL Server has no built-in function for this.
You have to write custom function for it.

Try this.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CamelCase]
(@Str varchar(8000))
RETURNS varchar(8000) AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Result varchar(2000)
  SET @Str = LOWER(@Str) + ' '
  SET @Result = ''
  WHILE 1=1
  BEGIN
    IF PATINDEX('% %',@Str) = 0 BREAK
    SET @Result = @Result + UPPER(Left(@Str,1))+
    SubString  (@Str,2,CharIndex(' ',@Str)-1)
    SET @Str = SubString(@Str,
      CharIndex(' ',@Str)+1,Len(@Str))
  END
  SET @Result = Left(@Result,Len(@Result))
  RETURN @Result
END
```

**Output :**

```
Input String    : 'microSoft sql server'
Output String   : 'Microsoft Sql Server'
```

Comment: Nice, but only handles spaces as delimiters.  Will not handle Dashes/Hyphens for example, but still answers the the question.  Will also not handle NULL, returns an empty-string instead.

Comment: Also doesn't handle single letter strings (ie First Middle Last names as separate strings): dbo.CamelCase(p.FirstName), dbo.CamelCase(p.LastName), dbo.CamelCase(p.MiddleName)

Answer (score 7):

I'd have to go with "No, that does not exist". This based on several years of perusing the available string-functions in T-SQL and some pretty recent 5-day courses in SQL Server 2008 R2.

Of course, I still could be wrong :).

Answer (score 5):

If the goal of your operation is to prettify strings of Names then proper capitalization could be defined as the first letter of each word separated by non-alphabet characters.

Other solutions do not take into account:

1. Preserving spacing (especially trailing spaces).
2. Preserving NULL, empty-string, or a string of just spaces.
3. Handling more than just spaces (e.g. dashes, commas, underscores, etc...)
4. Handling more than one non-alpha character between words/tokens.
5. Handling exceptions (e.g. McDonald or III like in "James William
   Bottomtooth the III").

Note: My solution does not handle exceptions.
If you are very concerned about those, then I suggest writing a CLR C# assembly for those as it will be tricky, and strings are an area where C# excels.
Another solution on here tries to account for this, but it would still take "*ivan terrible the iv*" and output "**IV***an Terrible The IV*".

This is the function I came up with:

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[fs_PascalCase]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT'))
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[fs_PascalCase]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fs_PascalCase]
(
    @Text nVarChar(MAX)
)
RETURNS nVarChar(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
        SET @Text = LOWER(@Text)--This step is optional.  Keep if you want the code below to control all casing. - 11/26/2013 - MCR.
    DECLARE @New nVarChar(MAX) = (CASE WHEN @Text IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE '' END)--Still return null when source is null. - 11/26/2013 - MCR.
    DECLARE @Len   Int = LEN(REPLACE(@Text, ' ', '_'))--If you want to count/keep trailing-spaces, you MUST use this!!! - 11/26/2013 - MCR.
    DECLARE @Index Int = 1--Sql-Server is 1-based, not 0-based.
    WHILE (@Index <= @Len)
        IF (SUBSTRING(@Text, @Index, 1) LIKE '[^a-z]' AND @Index + 1 <= @Len)--If not alpha and there are more character(s).
            SELECT @New = @New + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Text, @Index, 2)), @Index = @Index + 2
        ELSE
            SELECT @New = @New +       SUBSTRING(@Text, @Index, 1) , @Index = @Index + 1

    --If @Text is null, then @Len will be Null, and everything will be null.
    --If @Text is '',   then (@Len - 1) will be -1, so ABS() it to use 1 instead, which will still return ''.
    RETURN ( UPPER(LEFT(@New, 1)) + RIGHT(@New, ABS(@Len - 1)) )
END
GO
```

You would call it like so:

```
SELECT dbo.fs_PascalCase(NULL)[Null],
       dbo.fs_PascalCase('')[EmptyString],
       dbo.fs_PascalCase('hello   how are-you TODAY    ')[LongString]
```

The output will look like this:
[image: PascalCase Output]

Answer (score 3):

**My Strategy**

- If the name is already in mixed case, trust that it’s right.
- If the name is not in mixed case, then do the following:
- Trim up the name to eliminate white space
- Account for the names that start with “Mc” like “McDavid”
- Account for names with apostrophes like O’Reilly
- Account for hyphenated names (married names) “Anderson-Johnson”
- Account for multiple word names like “La Russa”
- Make sure suffixes included in the names field are capitalized appropriately

**The Code**

Here's my original post on this:  [Converting String to Camel Case in SQL Server](http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/converting-names-to-mixed-casecamel-case-in-sql-server/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetCamelCaseName]
(
    @Name varchar(50)
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(50) WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
BEGIN
    -- Declare the return variable here
    DECLARE @NameCamelCase VARCHAR(50)  

    -- This is determining whether or not the name is in camel case already (if the 1st character is uppercase
    -- and the third is lower (because the 2nd could be an apostrophe).  To do this, you have to cast the 
    -- character as varbinary and compare it with the upper case of the character cast as varbinary.  

    IF (CAST(SUBSTRING(@Name, 1,1) as varbinary) = CAST(SUBSTRING(UPPER(@Name), 1, 1) as varbinary)         
            AND ((CAST(SUBSTRING(@Name, 2,1) as varbinary) = CAST(SUBSTRING(LOWER(@Name), 2, 1) as varbinary)
                    AND SUBSTRING(@Name, 2,1) != '''')
                or
                (CAST(SUBSTRING(@Name, 4,1) as varbinary) = CAST(SUBSTRING(LOWER(@Name), 4, 1) as varbinary)
                    AND SUBSTRING(@Name, 2,1) = '''')))

        BEGIN
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = RTRIM(LTRIM(@Name))
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' sr', ' Sr')           
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' jr', ' Jr')       
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' ii', ' II')   
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' iii', ' III')
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' DE ', ' de ')
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, 'macdonald', 'MacDonald')

            if (@NameCamelCase LIKE '% iv') -- avoid changing "Ivan" to "IVan"
                SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' iv', ' IV')

            if ((@NameCamelCase = 'i') or (@NameCamelCase = 'ii') or (@NameCamelCase = 'iii') or (@NameCamelCase = 'iv'))
                SELECT @NameCamelCase = UPPER(@NameCamelCase)

            RETURN @NameCamelCase       

        END

    ELSE

        BEGIN       

            SELECT @NameCamelCase = RTRIM(LTRIM(@Name))

            -- "Mc-"
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @Name LIKE 'mc%'
                        THEN UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Name, 1, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@Name, 2, 1)) + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Name, 3, 1))  + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@Name, 4, 47))
                    ELSE
                       UPPER(SUBSTRING(@Name, 1, 1)) + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@Name, 2, 49))
                END

            -- Apostrophes
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @NameCamelCase LIKE '%''%'
                        THEN SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, 1, CHARINDEX('''', @NameCamelCase) - 1) + ''''  + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX('''', @NameCamelCase) + 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX('''', @NameCamelCase) + 2, 50)
                    ELSE
                        @NameCamelCase
                END 


            -- Hyphenated names (do it twice to account for double hyphens)
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @NameCamelCase LIKE '%-%'
                        THEN SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @NameCamelCase) - 1) + '^'  + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX('-', @NameCamelCase) + 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX('-', @NameCamelCase) + 2, 50)
                    ELSE
                        @NameCamelCase
                END 

            SELECT @NameCamelCase = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @NameCamelCase LIKE '%-%'
                        THEN SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, 1, CHARINDEX('-', @NameCamelCase) - 1) + '^'  + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX('-', @NameCamelCase) + 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX('-', @NameCamelCase) + 2, 50)
                    ELSE
                        @NameCamelCase
                END 

            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, '^', '-')

            -- Multiple word names (do it twice to account for three word names)
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @NameCamelCase LIKE '% %'
                        THEN SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @NameCamelCase) - 1) + '?'  + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX(' ', @NameCamelCase) + 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX(' ', @NameCamelCase) + 2, 50)
                    ELSE
                        @NameCamelCase
                END 

            SELECT @NameCamelCase = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @NameCamelCase LIKE '% %'
                        THEN SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @NameCamelCase) - 1) + '?'  + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX(' ', @NameCamelCase) + 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX(' ', @NameCamelCase) + 2, 50)
                    ELSE
                        @NameCamelCase
                END 

            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, '?', ' ')

            -- Names in Parentheses         
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = 
                CASE 
                    WHEN @NameCamelCase LIKE '%(%'
                        THEN SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, 1, CHARINDEX('(', @NameCamelCase) - 1) + '('  + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX('(', @NameCamelCase) + 1, 1)) + SUBSTRING(@NameCamelCase, CHARINDEX('(', @NameCamelCase) + 2, 50)
                    ELSE
                        @NameCamelCase
                END 


            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' sr', ' Sr')           
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' jr', ' Jr')           
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' ii', ' II')
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' iii', ' III')
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' DE ', ' de ')
            SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, 'macdonald', 'MacDonald')

            if (@NameCamelCase LIKE '% iv')
                SELECT @NameCamelCase = REPLACE(@NameCamelCase, ' iv', ' IV')

            if ((@NameCamelCase = 'i') or (@NameCamelCase = 'ii') or (@NameCamelCase = 'iii') or (@NameCamelCase = 'iv'))
                SELECT @NameCamelCase = UPPER(@NameCamelCase)

            -- Return the result of the function
            RETURN ISNULL(@NameCamelCase, '')

        END

    RETURN ISNULL(@NameCamelCase, '')

END
```

Comment: I like where you are going with this.  However, this code did not execute for me under SQL Server 2008 R2. The errors were "Must declare the scalar variable "@NameCamelCase".".

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to make it a bit simpler and missed a few things.  Updating now...

Comment: voted up for this: "If the name is already in mixed case, trust that it’s right."

Answer (score 3):

With SQL 2017 the function could look like this:

```
create function dbo.cap_words (@str varchar(max))
returns varchar(max)
as
begin
    declare @result varchar(max);
    select @result = string_agg( upper(left(value,1)) + substring(value,2,999),' ') from string_split(lower(@str),' ') 
    return @result;
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Like me, many people may be looking for an in-query solution, query creating function, well I figured out a different approach:

```
SELECT REPLACE(
    STUFF( 
        (SELECT' '+ LTRIM(RTRIM(UPPER(SUBSTRING(value, 1,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(value, 2, LEN(value)))))
         FROM STRING_SPLIT([Message], ' ')
         FOR XML PATH('')
         ), 1, 1, ''
   ), ''/*Control delimiters here*/, '') FROM [dbo].[MessageQueue]
```

Change [MessageQueue] table for your own table, and [Message] for your field.

The function STRING_SPLIT may require to increase your SQL compatibility level to 130.

Use the outer REPLACE function to set any delimiter you want.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken @ashish.chotalia's answer, and converted it to a temporary procedure with an output parameter. Might be handy for someone if you are not allowed to create functions in production databases, but you do need this functionality.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#InitCap') IS NOT NULL 
  DROP PROCEDURE #InitCap
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE #InitCap ( @InputString varchar(4000), @OutputString varchar(4000) OUTPUT) 
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Index          INT;
  DECLARE @Char           CHAR(1);
  DECLARE @PrevChar       CHAR(1);

  SET @OutputString = LOWER(@InputString);
  SET @Index = 1;

  WHILE @Index <= LEN(@InputString)
  BEGIN
    SET @Char     = SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index, 1);
    SET @PrevChar = CASE WHEN @Index = 1 THEN ' '
                         ELSE SUBSTRING(@InputString, @Index - 1, 1)
                    END;

    IF @PrevChar IN (' ', ';', ':', '!', '?', ',', '.', '_', '-', '/', '&', '''', '(')
    BEGIN
      SET @OutputString = STUFF(@OutputString, @Index, 1, UPPER(@Char));
    END;

    SET @Index = @Index + 1;
  END
END
GO

DECLARE @Name NVARCHAR(4000)= 'my string to convert. test/test something:else';
EXEC #InitCap @Name, @OutputString = @Name OUTPUT;
SELECT @Name;
```

Answer (score -10):

Here is simple thing, don't make it complicated.

Oracle:
SELECT initcap(lower('This is MY striNg to conVerT')) FROM dual;

Comment: The question is regarding sqlserver not oracle.

Comment: You can delete your answer to avoid to get negative score