# How to capitalize first letter each words in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

For example I've table `Student` with field `Name` and I want to change 'jason mraz' in field `Name` into 'Jason Mraz'. How the syntax in SQL Server?

Thanks for answers.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15290754/sql-capitalize-first-letter-only

Comment: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/functions/initcap.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The name for that sort of syntax is "Camel Case"

It looks like there might already be a solution @ [is there any sql server built-in function to convert string in camel case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164201/is-there-any-sql-server-built-in-function-to-convert-string-in-camel-case)

Comment: Avoid link only answers

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[CapitalizeFirstLetter]
(
--string need to format
@string VARCHAR(200)--increase the variable size depending on your needs.
)
RETURNS VARCHAR(200)
AS

BEGIN
--Declare Variables
DECLARE @Index INT,
@ResultString VARCHAR(200)--result string size should equal to the @string variable size
--Initialize the variables
SET @Index = 1
SET @ResultString = ''
--Run the Loop until END of the string

WHILE (@Index <LEN(@string)+1)
BEGIN
IF (@Index = 1)--first letter of the string
BEGIN
--make the first letter capital
SET @ResultString =
@ResultString + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@string, @Index, 1))
SET @Index = @Index+ 1--increase the index
END

-- IF the previous character is space or '-' or next character is '-'

ELSE IF ((SUBSTRING(@string, @Index-1, 1) =' 'or SUBSTRING(@string, @Index-1, 1) ='-' or SUBSTRING(@string, @Index+1, 1) ='-') and @Index+1 <> LEN(@string))
BEGIN
--make the letter capital
SET
@ResultString = @ResultString + UPPER(SUBSTRING(@string,@Index, 1))
SET
@Index = @Index +1--increase the index
END
ELSE-- all others
BEGIN
-- make the letter simple
SET
@ResultString = @ResultString + LOWER(SUBSTRING(@string,@Index, 1))
SET
@Index = @Index +1--incerase the index
END
END--END of the loop

IF (@@ERROR
<> 0)-- any error occur return the sEND string
BEGIN
SET
@ResultString = @string
END
-- IF no error found return the new string
RETURN @ResultString
END
```