# Insert query to insert name into db

Tags: sql

I want to store my user information into database with Uname first letter upper case and lname first letter uppercase. Doesn't matter how user insert data, it should be store in db as

- Input: sachin tendulkar
- Database: Sachin Tendulkar

I need Insert query for this. I know we can use update / select query but specially looking for insert query.

Appreciate your answer.

Thanks,

Comment: What DBMS are you using? (MySQL, SQL-Server, Oracle, etc...)?

Comment: Also first and last names are stored in one or separate columns?

Comment: Possible duplication : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164201/is-there-any-sql-server-built-in-function-to-convert-string-in-camel-case

Comment: You'll need a trigger to take care of the Capitalization. Tag dbms used, since triggers are usually product specific. (Only a very few dbms products have ANSL SQL triggers.)

Answer (score 0):

In *SQL Server*. If first and last names are stored in separate columns you can do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE #Tbl
(
    FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
DECLARE @FirstName NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'tom'

INSERT INTO #Tbl (FirstName) VALUES (UPPER(LEFT(@FirstName,1))+LOWER(SUBSTRING(@FirstName,2,LEN(@FirstName))))
```