# Change format of text to Camel Case in Sybase

Tags: case, sybase

I will like to change the format of text values in a column to camel case in Sybase 
For example   NEW YORK should be New York

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?), and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Sybase IQ. I am new to Sybase and the unique text functions I have encountered so far are UPPER and LOWER.

Comment: I don't think IQ (or SQLAnywhere, which IQ uses as a front end) have anything like Oracle's `initcap()` so you'll likely need to write your own; a quick search brings up multiple hits, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55054/7366100) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5164201/7366100)