# Add spaces to Camelcase with Caps in it

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, camelcasing

I have an external app passing strings in camelcase. Users are looking to report on the string and want it formatted as a sentence. The string may have words in it with all caps that I need to add spaces around.

built out a function based on this question here: [Is there any SQL Server built-in function to convert string in camel case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5164201/is-there-any-sql-server-built-in-function-to-convert-string-in-camel-case)
however, it does not work with the all caps words. Below is my modified version.

```
DECLARE @String    NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ThisIsASentenceWithCAPTIInIt'
    --, @Len       INT         --  = LEN(@String)
      , @Delimiter CHAR(1)       = ' '
      , @Iterator  INT           = 2; --Don't put space to left of first even if it's a capital

WHILE @Iterator <= LEN(@String)
-- Iterate through string
    BEGIN
        -- Check if current character is Uppercase (lowercase = 0)
        IF PATINDEX('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]', SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) <> 0
        -- Do this if capital
            BEGIN
                -- check if the previous character is lowercase, if it is then add a space before the current character.
                IF(
                   (PATINDEX('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]', SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator - 1, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) = 0
                    AND SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator - 1, 1) <> ' '
                   )
                   OR PATINDEX('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]', SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator + 1, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        SET @String = STUFF(@String, @Iterator, 0, @Delimiter);
                        SET @Iterator+=1;
                END;
                -- check if the next character is lowercase, if it is then add a space before the current character.
                SET @Iterator+=1;
        END;
        ---- Don't care about current character being lowercase. Just continue iterating
        SET @Iterator+=1;
    END;

SELECT @String;
```

Example of what I get from the app - "ThisIsASentenceWithCAPTIInIt"

What I want to pass back - "This Is A Sentence With CAPTI In It"

What I am getting back from my modified version - "This Is ASentence With CAPTIIn It"

Comment: I really don't think SQL Server is the best choice here (in my opinion). You would be far better using a CLR or application to do this.

Comment: Also, it'll be worthwhile posting your version of SQL Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my suggestion:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(100)='ThisIsASentenceWithCAPTIInIt';

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Position
          ,@s AS Original
          ,CAST(SUBSTRING(@s,1,1) AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS GrowingString
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.Position+1
          ,cte.Original
          ,CONCAT(cte.GrowingString 
          ,CurrentLetter
          ,CASE WHEN CurrentCapit=0 AND NextCapit=1 THEN ' ' ELSE 
                CASE WHEN CurrentCapit=1 AND NextCapit=1 AND ThirdCapit=0 THEN ' ' ELSE '' END END ) AS GrowingString
    FROM cte
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT SUBSTRING(@s,cte.Position+1,1) CurrentLetter
                      ,SUBSTRING(@s,cte.Position+2,1) NextLetter
                      ,SUBSTRING(@s,cte.Position+3,1)ThirdLetter) A
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN ASCII(CurrentLetter) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END CurrentCapit
                      ,CASE WHEN ASCII(NextLetter) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END NextCapit
                      ,CASE WHEN ASCII(ThirdLetter) BETWEEN 65 AND 90 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ThirdCapit) B
    WHERE cte.Position < LEN(@s)
)
SELECT TOP 1 GrowingString
FROM cte
ORDER BY Position DESC;
```

The idea in short:

We use a recursive CTE. The simple approach will just read the string character by character and will return the whole string in `GrowingString` at the end. This would be just the same as the original string.

The tricky part is: Where to insert spaces?

If the current letter is not capitalized and the next is, we need a space. That's for sure. Furthermore, the embedded `CASE` will test if the current and the next letter is capitalized but the third one. In this case we need the space too.

Comment: This was very efficient compared to what I was doing. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

doing it this in SQL Server is not the best choice. also rewriting existing string can be challenging somewhat challenging.

I think there are many more way to simplify this code, but here is a version that I believe will achieve the result you are looking for.

```
DECLARE @String    NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'ThisIsASentenceWithCAPTIInIt'
    --, @Len       INT         --  = LEN(@String)
      , @Delimiter CHAR(1)       = ' '
      , @Iterator  INT           = 1; --Don't put space to left of first even if it's a capital

DECLARE @retval nvarchar(max) = '';

WHILE @Iterator <= LEN(@String)
-- Iterate through string
    BEGIN
        -- Check if current character is Uppercase (lowercase = 0)
        IF PATINDEX('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]', SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) <> 0
        -- Do this if capital
            BEGIN
                -- check if the previous character is lowercase, if it is then add a space before the current character.
                IF(
                   (PATINDEX('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]', SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator - 1, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) = 0
                    AND SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator - 1, 1) <> ' '
                   )
                   OR PATINDEX('[ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]', SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator + 1, 1) COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AI) = 0)
                    BEGIN
                        set @retval += ' ' ;
                        --SET @String = STUFF(@String, @Iterator, 0, @Delimiter);
                        --SET @Iterator+=1;
                END;
                -- check if the next character is lowercase, if it is then add a space before the current character.
                --Set @retval += SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator, 1);
                --SET @Iterator+=1;
            END;
        ---- Don't care about current character being lowercase. Just continue iterating
        Set @retval += SUBSTRING(@String, @Iterator, 1);
        SET @Iterator+=1;
    END;
SET @retval = Ltrim(@retval);
SELECT @retval;
```